# How to force Emacs not use Mountain Lion's full screen style

Tags: emacs

I'm a heavy Emacs user. However, on my Mac, if I switch Emacs to fullscreen mode, it will use Mountain Lion's fullscreen style, which places Emacs on another desktop. In this fullscreen mode, the 2 top lines are wasted since I cannot use them for displaying the Emacs buffer (you can see in the picture below). Also, the animation when I change desktop is annoying.

I wonder if there is any solution to force Emacs not use Mountain Lion's fullscreen style. I just want a maximize displaying area (hide the menu bar, hide the title bar,...) like when I playing video in fullscreen with VLC 1.x

Comment: You forgot to attach the picture ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following:

- Auto-hide the menu bar using `(setq ns-auto-hide-menu-bar t)`
- Hide the tool bar using `(tool-bar-mode -1)` (I haven't found it useful.)
- Place the title bar above the top of the screen. Although it's not possible to drag it there, the Mac OS X port allows you to place it there programatically. For example, you could do this using: `(set-frame-position (selected-frame) 0 -24)`. **Note**: this requires the menu bar to be hidden.
- Resize the window to the desired size, e.g. `(set-frame-size (selected-frame) 80 85)`. (Unfortunately, due to limitations in the OS, you can't manually resize the frame to be higher than the display.)

With a 6x8 font, the editing area will be 148 lines on a 1600x1200 monitor. I use two such monitors, and split my Emacs frame into six columns. By using `follow-mode`, I can see 888 consecutive lines of code.

Comment: I love it -- hide the menu bar !!!!  :) -- this gives me the excuse I've been waiting for to put the date / time in my mode-line.

Comment: great solution ;) however, the set-frame-position function doesn't work for me, the title bar (which contains close, minimize and maximize buttons) is still there at the top left of the screen

Comment: Try a newer Emacs. The features I refer to are quite new additions. (Which version are you using?)

Comment: I use this one `GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.36) of 2013-03-13 on bob.porkrind.org`, downloaded from here http://emacsformacosx.com/

Comment: `(setq ns-auto-hide-menu-bar t)` is very helpful on a multi-monitor setup.

Comment: @tmtxt, I just tested that exact version. It seems to work properly, but only when the menu bar is hidden first. Also, I just updated the answer with info on how to hide the tool bar.

Comment: yes my mac menu bar is hidden already using `(setq ns-auto-hide-menu-bar t)`, however the title bar is still there, I cannot move it up. is there anything special to your mac? which version of MacOS are you using?

Comment: @tmtxt, I've got 10.9 but I used this on 10.6 as well. Nothing special that I'm aware of... (Btw, I'm the one who implemented these features in Emacs, so I really would like to know why it doesn't work for you.)

Comment: @Lindydancer I'm using 10.8.5 now, have you tried it on 10.8? I have quit other applications to make sure that they don't affect emacs but the result is still the same.

Comment: No, not on 10.8, however, another Emacs developer says he has. (He had some kind of problem about six months ago, but said they have since disappeared.) Unfortunately, I don't have access to a 10.8-machine...

Comment: @Lindydancer ok let me try to examine the problem. if I can find the cause I will let you know to update that feature

Comment: @Lindydancer can you give me the list of the packages that you install into emacs? I use emacs starter kit, maybe there are some problems with it

Comment: Oh, that list would be looong... However, it works for me when I start Emacs with the -Q option, i.e. without loading any extra emacs packages. I would put my money on it being related to 10.8, or some setting in the OS. Btw, you could try a "nightly build" of Emacs, there might be bug fixes in the trunk which haven't yet made it to an official release.

Comment: -Q did not work for me but the nightly version did. I tried the latest nightly build Emacs-2013-12-21_01-33-31-115660-universal-10.6.8.dmg from this site http://emacsformacosx.com/builds  However, there is another problem. you can see in the picture here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12687135/emacs.png I can move the window up out of the screen border, but I cannot resize the bottom edge of the window. it the maximum I can resize

Comment: Yes, I see the problem, and I get the same thing here under 10.9. However, it looks as though it's possible to resize the frame programatically using something like `(set-frame-size (selected-frame) 80 83)`.

Comment: great! now it works as expected. thank you very much! I'm waiting for the stable version

Answer (score 7):

Emacs 24 has an option not to use the separate-desktop-fullscreen Mac OS thing:

```lisp
(setq ns-use-native-fullscreen nil)
```

It still covers the whole screen including the dock, and hides the window title bar.

After setting this variable up, you can switch to fullscreen using <kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>toggle-frame-fullscreen</kbd>.

Also, don't forget to hide the useless toolbar:

```lisp
(tool-bar-mode -1)
```

Comment: I'm using Emacs 24.3, which version of Emacs are you using? I don't find the variable ns-use-native-fullscreen and the toggle-frame-fullscreen function. Does it need any patch?

Comment: @tmtxt, I'm using Emacs installed from brew: `brew install emacs --cocoa --srgb`.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work by clicking the maximize button in the toolbar instead of manually calling `toggle-frame-fullscreen`? (using it uses lion style fullscreen) MacVim does this when turning off lion mode.

Answer (score 2):

```
(toggle-frame-maximized)
```

You may need a developer build (e.g., Emacs Trunk) for this feature if your older version does not have it.  However, the menubar and frame title will still be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Now I use Emacs with -nox in iTerm2.  You can nicely full-screen iTerm2 and avoid animations using TotalSpaces2 (though it costs $10 or so).  With triggers in Quicksilver, I have it pretty much like Xmonad now.  (It sucks Apple doesn't support turning off animated window switches.)

Comment: I use quicksilver triggers, too. However, the problem is when I have many terminal windows opened, the trigger only activate the terminal application. It cannot know which window in iTerm2 to jump directly to